# Query Buider Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Can somebody help me,

This My database sql query for
[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In4RX.jpg)

```
SELECT supplier,
MAX(IF(item_name = 'Lemon', price, NULL)) AS Lemon,
MAX(IF(item_name = 'Apple', price, NULL)) AS Apple,
MAX(IF(item_name = 'Durian', price, NULL)) AS Durian,
MAX(IF(item_name = 'Mango', price, NULL)) AS Mango
FROM offer
where status = 'open'
GROUP BY supplier
```

how use this query by Laravel QueryBuilder ? Thank's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$results = DB::table('offer')->select(DB::raw("supplier,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Lemon', price, NULL)) AS Lemon,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Apple', price, NULL)) AS Apple,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Durian', price, NULL)) AS Durian,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Mango', price, NULL)) AS Mango"))
->where('status', 'open')
->groupBy('supplier')
->get();
```

Really, Query Builder isn't made for complicated queries.  When they get that complicated, you might find it easier just to use raw statements:

```
$results = DB::select("SELECT supplier,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Lemon', price, NULL)) AS Lemon,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Apple', price, NULL)) AS Apple,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Durian', price, NULL)) AS Durian,
    MAX(IF(item_name = 'Mango', price, NULL)) AS Mango
FROM offer
where status = 'open'
GROUP BY supplier");
```

Comment: Thanks @Captain Hypertext, your answered save my day, This working perfectly ,,,

Comment: Hy @CaptainHypertext, Thanks a lot for your previous answers, i have one more problem in my queries , Can i make the query more dynamic for 'item_name' or 'supplier' column.
In the previous example I have 4 'item_name' **( Mango, Apple, Durian, Lemon)** . I really do not know how I can insert the function in my queries.
Because in the real case 'item_name' is unlimited, it could be one or more

Comment: @CristalTravel I didn't really take time to study the logic of your query, just the implementation.  What exactly are you trying to do with this query?  Why do certain items end up NULL while others have a price?  Also what is your table structure?

Comment: thank's for you'r response,
I want to make a program offering price to some suppliers, where the item needs will vary every time there is demand. So when a request is made, the client selects whatever item is needed and will choose which suppliers will be offered. So 1 item can be offered to several suppliers.
Then, when the request is made at all the price is empty, the price column will be filled after getting the response from the supplier. .
So the core of this logic is to compare the lowest prices of some suppliers on offer.

Comment: one more in that logic, not all items needed will be offered to each supplier, in the previous example there are 4 items in need right, but there are suppliers who only get 2 offers, so for items not offered it will be worth null ,,,